# Do we have any way to optimize this similarity query?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Do we have any way to optimize the similarity query even more?

The query took 40ms, the table just has 100 000 rows:

```
Explain Analyze SELECT md_comic_id, similarity (md_titles.title, 'Omega ni dake wa naritakunai!! ~Isekai tensei shitara ane no bl manga') AS sml, title
FROM
    md_titles
WHERE
    'Omega ni dake wa naritakunai!! ~Isekai tensei shitara ane no bl manga' % title
ORDER BY
    sml DESC
LIMIT '30';
```

**The table was indexed:**

[image]

**The Query Plan:**

```
Limit  (cost=252.71..252.77 rows=21 width=37) (actual time=39.445..39.447 rows=4 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=252.71..252.77 rows=21 width=37) (actual time=39.444..39.445 rows=4 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: (similarity((title)::text, 'Omega ni dake wa naritakunai!! ~Isekai tensei shitara ane no bl manga'::text)) DESC"
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on md_titles  (cost=228.96..252.25 rows=21 width=37) (actual time=34.037..39.438 rows=4 loops=1)
              Filter: ('Omega ni dake wa naritakunai!! ~Isekai tensei shitara ane no bl manga'::text % (title)::text)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 468
              Heap Blocks: exact=359
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on md_titles_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..228.96 rows=21 width=0) (actual time=30.886..30.887 rows=472 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((title)::text % 'Omega ni dake wa naritakunai!! ~Isekai tensei shitara ane no bl manga'::text)
Planning Time: 1.525 ms
Execution Time: 39.476 ms
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to our site dba.se.

Comment: check this out: 
[help me write this query in sql.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)







Please edit your question following [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)


Check this link out:[How to ask help about a query](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

The performance of trigram similarity queries depends very heavily on the nature of the data, which is hard to describe or summarize without just sharing the whole dataset.

One possible solution is to build a gist_trgm_ops index, and then use the KNN mechanism which would need to have the query look like this:

```
Explain Analyze SELECT md_comic_id, similarity (md_titles.title, 'Omega ni dake wa naritakunai!! ~Isekai tensei shitara ane no bl manga') AS sml, title
FROM
    md_titles
WHERE
    'Omega ni dake wa naritakunai!! ~Isekai tensei shitara ane no bl manga' % title
ORDER BY
    'Omega ni dake wa naritakunai!! ~Isekai tensei shitara ane no bl manga' <-> title
LIMIT '30';
```

It is hard to predict ahead of time how this will do, just try it and see.

That whole phrase is pretty long to be applying trigram similarity to.  Perhaps you could look into methods from Full Text Search features instead.